# DataTables - Specify page size on server side

Tags: laravel, datatables, pagination

When using [DataTables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables), how can I control page size on the server-side? I want to take advantage of bult-in navigation buttons (prev, next etc.), but don't want clients to be able to dictate page size.

The only option I see is `pageLength` which controls page size from client's end, which defeats the purpose in my case.

This is Laravel application and I'm using Yajra package ([DataTables as a Service](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service)) implementation. Note that I can't use Eloquent's built-in pagination because then I'll have to manage navigation myself and will also need to disable DataTable's own navigation because that one depends on `pageLength`.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to remove the present page size in the datatable by adding paging to false on data table options.

Then u can do pagination by simply add laravel pagination class when dragging data from your models. E.g

$all_items = user model::paginate($page_size,['*'],'page_no');

The last variable of the paginate method is just indicating the parameter name of the page no. Useful when you have more than pagination in a page. It can be changed to whatever unique value u like.